# Django different types of user

Tags: python, django

I want to build a simple website with Django, and so far I have made a sign-up form that everyone can sign up and publish some announcement.

For next stage I want to make the user can only view the announcement by default, I also want to have another type of user can view and create an announcement.

*How should I build my user model and sign up forms? Should I use things like permission or AbstractUser?*

**the current sign up forms.py I am using is like**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "Display name"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"
```

and the views about the announcement is like

```
#show all announcement
class AnnouncementListView(ListView):
    ...

#show a specific announcement
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

#create a announcement
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    ...
```

***Thanks!***

Comment: Have you looked at the basic permissions and group tutorials?

Comment: I tried to use the admin site to create two types of groups, and assign no permission to the normal user group, but they are still able to create an announcement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create groups (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/) from the django admin. Then write decorator for your CreatePostView.https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/